# How to pass jQuery variable with AJAX to PHP page

Tags: jquery

Trying to pass the variable  "flickrurl" to a PHP page with jQuery/ajax. It works when using a plain text string and not the variable. Am I assigning  the variable properly?   [See the full code in action here](http://www.fletcherboland.com/fb/4/):

```
$trash.droppable({
                accept: '#gallery > li',
                activeClass: 'ui-state-highlight',
                drop: function(ev, ui) {
                    deleteImage(ui.draggable);
                                //set variable equal to src of image tag in #gallery > li
                        var  $flickrurl =  $item.find('img').attr("src");
                //pass variable to php page
                      $.post("updateDB.php", $flickrurl );

                }
            });
```

Comment: So you're going to thank ceejayoz but not accept his answer?

Comment: Hey @Walden, what Bradley is getting at is that its best for everyone (you, ceejayoz, the community) if you mark his answer as accepted. It puts a huge green check next to the answer to let future users know it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's AJAX functions expect data in JSON form. Try:

```
$.post("updateDB.php", { 'flickrurl': $flickrurl } );
```

Comment: I tried to click the check when I tested the solution, but for some reason it didn't take.