# Using jQuery variable in PHP page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery Ajax to store some value in MySql DB

So far I'm passing a start_time as a datetime object like

```
Wed Aug 15 2012 14:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

and I'm getting this value on my php page like

```
1345019400
```

in my db, I want to store that value like

```
2012-8-17 20:45
```

so the $_POST['start_time']  that value is looking like an integer(I'm not sure )

my question is what to do with that integer value so that it could store in my db like

```
2012-8-17 20:45
```

Comment: see this url:--


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838756/how-to-pass-jquery-variable-with-ajax-to-php-page

Comment: thanks to all of you for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$bla=1345019400;

$date=date('Y-m-d H:i',$bla);
echo $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "integer" is a timestamp! Format it using the PHP [DateTime::format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) function

Answer (score 0):

You get timestamp so you have to transform it using `date` function:

```
<?php
    $date = date('YYYY-mm-dd hh:ii', $_POST['start_time']);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a timestamp. Have a look at the PHP date function to format it.

Answer (score 0):

your php needs to format it into mysql date format before it inserts (assuming the data type on your column is DATETIME)

Check out the way php works with dates.

Also if you are having trouble with the date converting, convert it all to an Epoch string between javascript and php, then convert it just before insertion.

Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: No worries (+1) me if you want :P

Comment: P.S the DATETIME format for mysql is: "YYYY-mm-DD hh:MM:ss" so use that in your php functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
date("M-d-Y g:i", $date);
```

read documentation for function date()